# I want to get a graph of the labaratory rabbit limb movement

Tags: capture, motion

I have a video file with rabbit's jump. This rabbit have 3 points [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCNVx.png) (red, green, blue) on his leg. I want to get motion graph of[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oO1k7.png) these points and absolutely don't know how to do it! Help!

I don't know anything about motion capture!